# :command to abort sequence?

Tags: global-command, command

To be honest upfront, I wanted to use `global` to find the first non-matching line, as in

```
v,/usr/lib/, abort
```

(having slashes in the search pattern is the reason for using `g` instead of `/` — I'm editing a list of files)

Yes, I know there are other ways to do it. But is there something like an abort command that causes `g` to abort immediately and not process any more matches?

Comment: You're not using regular search (`/`) because you have slashes in your search term? You don't want to just escape the slashes? (`/\/usr\/lib\/`)

Comment: AFAIK, only `:throw` or another unsuccessful command (which de facto throws something for any reason).

Comment: add an invalid command (or just use abort as command :). Not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: It seems unfair that `s,,,` can change the delimiter, but `/` can't, so out of principle I want to find a way around. It seems that both using `nosuchcmd` or `throw 'err'` stop `global`and leave the cursor on the match. I... guess that works. Though that's not a graceful exit

Comment: Please better explain what problem you want to solve. It seems a bit unusual to me.

Comment: Why not use vglobal and get all the non-matching lines? You can add them to the quickfix list and then use `:cfirst` to get the first one using the example at `:help :caddexpr`

Answer (score 1):

While looking for a different way to do achieve my initial goal (find next non-matching line), [B Layer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/11054/b-layer) came up with `:.,$v// vis`: see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28540/30091