# Skip to next batch of search results (or find next non-match)?

Tags: key-bindings, search, navigation

So you search `/needle`, and end up trapped in a haystack of result lines. Is there a quick way to skip to the first non-matching line (and then the next batch of results)?

E.g. I'm viewing the results of `updatedb -v`, which shows paths considered by the `locate` engine, and I'm trying to figure out why a particular *.svg file isn't beeing considered. Searching for `/svg` leads me first somewhere deep inside `/home/user/`, where there are a whole lot of `.*svg` lines. How can I easily skip over all contiguous matches and go to the first non-matching line (and then probably repeat and so on)? Perhaps define a key mapping that reverses the search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to come up with something fairly short and found this novel approach (novel to me anyways...I'd never tried it before).

There is an inverse counterpart to `:g` (global command): `:v`. This will run specified commands on all lines that *don't* match the given pattern. Because it's really easy  to invoke when a pattern is already in use (i.e. `:v// {cmds}`, I was wondering if there's a way to break out of it easily at the first line it operates on (i.e. the first line below the cursor without the offending pattern). I found that `:visual` does the trick. (See update, though.)

One added requirement, though, is that you need to give a range or the process will begin at the start of the file which we definitely don't want. So what you want is a range starting with the current line (`.`) and going as far as the end of the buffer (`$`)...

```
:.,$v// vis
```

and that's it. You'll be on the next line that doesn't have the pattern. It's easy to map it, too...

```
:nnoremap <leader>x :.,$v// vis<cr>
```

The nice thing with this approach is that you don't need to use a different search and thus you won't have to deal with getting your original search back as the active one. If there is a downside to it it may be a little slow depending on various factors (i.e. YMMV).

**Update:** A twist. `:visual` is actually behaving as `:e` and the above will not work cleanly if the file has unsaved changes. Do `:w` before running the above and it will work as described.

Comment: Very nice finding!

Comment: @filbranden Thanks. (Regarding, `:e`...yes but we are in Ex mode, fortunately.)

Comment: Not really... If you execute the `:v` command with `:vis` in an unnamed modified buffer, you'll see it warns that the file is modified... If you execute the `:.,$v//e` you'll see it behaves the same. You'll also see it prints the file name and all. It's using the `:e` behavior.

Comment: I tested on a file with unsaved changes and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I get `E37: No write since last change`. I'm betting you have `:set hidden` and that's why you don't see the E37 message (just editing the same file again, means switching to the buffer you're already in.)

Comment: I thought you mean Ex command line mode. You're talking about the actual but obscure Ex. The behavior I'm seeing is not matching up fully with some things. That includes what's described at the very end of `:h :v`. For now you'll just have to avoid running the command with an unsaved file. Do a `:w` beforehand.

Comment: I still think it's a great find! It's just that the explanation on `:visual` repeatedly going back to visual mode when `:g` or `:v` is run from Ex mode means *actual* Ex mode that you get to with `Q`. If you see `:help :visual` you'll see that when you're not in Ex mode it's a synonym to `:edit` and I'm fairly sure this is the behavior that is being triggered here. Which is enough to stop the `:v` and that's indeed very useful! So I really like your finding, it's just I think your explanation of it might not be totally accurate (which is completely understandable, from the docs.)

Comment: I only read `:h :visual` before writing the above. I discovered the other part afterwards. I fully comprehend everything that's documented...it's not behaving that way for me. Clearly I have something in my configuration that's interfering. Doubt I'll dig further since it's not going to change anything in the answer now that I noted the need for `:w`.

Comment: Time for a break. And anyways, I can't earn any more rep today because some wonderful, anonymous person upvoted a bunch of my answers. Thought it was a general gift from SE for all at first but I checked a few profiles and they didn't have it. My guardian angel, I guess. :)

Comment: @BLayer, I came up with almost the same answer a while ago, except I didn't think about a no-op, but some kind of :throw or :abort. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26339/command-to-abort-sequence/28628#28628

Comment: @AldIn Heh. I totally forgot about that question. (Despite having left a comment under it!) Funny. I experimented with thrown error as well but it was far too noisy.